# data table or list in selecting data from db

Tags: c#, .net

i have max 50 employee each has 40 field which is better using data table or list,
what i want to do is read all employees from database and load them to data grid view , then user can select any employee and edit or delete ,
so if he want to edit employee record will passed to employee edit form to display the employee data ?
so which is better ?
pass record from list as object or from data table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are speaking from a performance view, DataTables are more expensive that Lists in both processor time and memory allocation.

However with a sample size of 50 Objects with 40 Properties each, the difference will be minor and you can use whichever structure you are more comfortable with.